# Проверять значение при нажатии на "Back"

Tags: android

Есть два activity MainActivity и WordActivity. Мне нужно чтобы при закрытии WordActivity (т.е. при отображении MainActivity) в MainActivity делать что-то. Подскажите есть ли какой-нибудь метод для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо запускать `WordActivity` с

`startActivityForResult`

```
static final int SOME_REQUEST = 123; //поле Mainactivity
...
//в методе где открываете WordActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(Mainactivity.this, WordActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_REQUEST);
```

и обрабатывать результат в

`onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SOME_REQUEST) {
        //здесь Вы вернулись с WordActivity
        //в зависимости от результата можете обработать действия
        //из Intent data можете доставать данные, если Вы туда их сложили в WordActivity
    }
}
```

[Подробная документация с примерами](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: И эти действия позволят в MainActivity что-то делать после того как закроется WordActivity ?

Comment: @Колхозник обновил ответ с несколькими комментариями.

Comment: Да, понял.. Спасибо. А если мне нужно обновить иконку  у кнопки которая находится в кастомном ListView. Из этого метода достать кнопку из этого ListView как-то можно?